# JavaScript scripts not working on my live server

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new around here so I'm probably doing something really wrong, basically I created an index.html file in which I refer to some other files, and they are working just fine, except for my script, I'm running it on vscode with live server, and it simply does not work. It works only if I open the file itself with live server, can someone please help me? Btw, the script which I'm talking about is the last one in the second code block.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Exercícios HTML</title>
    <style>
        #conteudo {
            padding: 30px 0px;
            font-size: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>EXERCÍCIOS HTML</h1>
    </header>

    <nav>
        <a href="exercicios/opcao1.html"> 01 - Tags mais usadas</a> 
        <a href="exercicios/opcao2.html"> 02 - Rato</a> 
        <a href="exercicios/opcao3.html"> 03 - Outras tags</a> 
        <a href="exercicios/listas.html"> 04 - Listinhas</a> 
        <a href="exercicios/listaAninhada.html"> 05 - Listinhas Aninhadas</a> 
        <a href="exercicios/links.html"> 06 - LINKS</a>


    </nav>

    <section section id = 'conteudo'></section>
    <footer> <br> Curso de web moderno</footer>

    <script>
        document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(link => {
            const conteudo = document.getElementById('conteudo')
            
            link.onclick = function(e){
                e.preventDefault()
            fetch(link.href)
                .then(resp => resp.text())
                .then(html => conteudo.innerHTML = html)
        }})
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<h1>Projeto</h1>
<ul class = 'tree'>
    <li>
        <span wm-folder> backend</span>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <span wm-folder>app</span>
                <ul>
                    <li>produto.js</li>
                    <li>usuario.js</li>
                    <li>venda.js</li>
                </ul>
                <li>
                    <span wm-folder>config</span>
                    <ul>
                        <li>banco.js</li>
                        <li>rotas.js</li>
                        <li>servidor.js</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span wm-folder>frontend</span>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <span wm-folder>publics</span>
                <ul>
                    <li>rapp.css</li>
                    <li>ratazana.css</li>
                    <li>ratoupeira.css</li>

                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://files.cod3r.com.br/curso-web/tree.css">

<script>
    document.querySelectorAll('[wm-folder]').forEach(folder => {
        folder.onclick = function (e){
            console.log('teste')
            const ul = folder.nextElementSibling
            const display = ul.style.display
            ul.style.display = display == 'none' ? 'block' : 'none'
        }
    }) 
</script>
```

I tried reloading cache on my operagx browser, disable adblock, but nothing seems to work

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: oh you're right, found this "GET /favicon.ico" Error (404): "Not found"
but i can't understand

Comment: Does your browser address bar say "localhost" or does it say "File" ?

Comment: My browser address says an ip address wich ends with /HTML, im running it with live server extension

Comment: The favicon error can be ignored. What do you see in the console when you click one of your links that tries to fetch an external file?

Comment: your first page looks ok but the second page is just a fragment.  Where's the rest of the html?

Comment: actually, the links are working, the problem is that the script is not working when i run the index.html file as live server, only when i open the listasaninhadas.html file with live server. Basicaly, i wanted the nested list that i created to hide and show once the user clicks it, but it doesn't work if i do it through the index.html file, sorry for bad english.

Comment: The second page is just a fragment because i linked it to the index, i'm really new into this, so i don't know if i'm doing it correctly

Comment: I have no idea on how to explain it further so i uploaded a video explanining and showing it:

https://streamable.com/5np2ld

Aprreciate if someone could watch and help me

Answer (score 0):

Script elements injected inside another element through `innerHTML` will not be executed. You could consider using an `<iframe>` to show the content instead.

```html
<style>
#conteudo {
    padding: 30px 0px;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
}
</style>
<!-- ... -->
<iframe id='conteudo'></iframe>
<!-- ... -->
<script>
const conteudo = document.getElementById('conteudo');
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(link => {
    link.addEventListener('click', e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        conteudo.src = link.href;
    });
});
</script>
```